# Image in collection view cell inside of uitableviewcell does not take rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, xcode10.3

I have a tableview and in one of the rows, I have a custom cell which has a collection view with horizontal scroll. In the collection view cell I have the Image  for which I have added rounded corners.

```
img_Photo.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorFromCode(0xf2f2f2)
img_Photo.layer.cornerRadius = img_Photo.frame.height / 2
img_Photo.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

The corner radius shows as below first and then on scrolling it looks proper. What am I missing to set this properly.

I have added layoutIfNeeded in the tableviewcell

```
override func layoutIfNeeded() {
    super.layoutIfNeeded()
    collectView.frame = self.contentView.bounds
}
```

[image: on first load]

[image: after scrolling]

Comment: Basically what's happening is that when you set the corner radius at that time your- img_Photo.frame.height is different & then after scrolling  your img_Photo.frame.height changes. You can debug it using ViewDidLayoutSubViews Method. A solution could be to call self.view.layoutIfNeeded() before setting corner radius. Or reseting cornerRadius inside ViewDidLayoutSubview method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override layoutSubviews() inside your collection view cell class and set corner radius inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like this and use it in your xib Layout:

```
import UIKit

class RoundedView: UIView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height / 2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before returning your cell in cellForItemAtIndexPath method just add 
cell.layoutIfNeeded() before returning your cell.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)


    cell.layoutIfNeeded()// this is to be added in your code
    return cell
}
```